# sorting child list from parent in java 8

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-8

Parent is a class which is inherited by Child. which is inherited by `GrandChild`. Each class contains List of the child class(i.e Parent contains `List` of `Child` and `Child` contains `List` of `GrandChild`). Each class contains 50 attributes(`attrib1`-`atrib50`). `getChildList()` returns the `arrayList` of objects of type `Child`. `getGrandChildList()` returns the `arrayList` of objects of type `GrandChild`

Let `resultSet` be `List` of `Parent`

```
List<Parent> resultSet
```

Now I want to sort the list based on some attributes. For example if I want to sort `resultSet` based on two parent attributes(say Attribute 1 and attribute 2, I use this code.

```
Comparator<Parent> byFirst = (e1, e2) -> e2.getAttrib1().compareTo(e1.getAttrib1());
Comparator<Parent> bySecond = (e1, e2) -> e1.getAttrib2().compareTo(e2.getAttrib2());

Comparator<Parent> byThird = byFirst.thenComparing(bySecond);

resultSet.sort(byThird);
```

Now my next criteria is to sort each child separately.
For example, if my condition is attribute15 of child list, then I want to sort each child list by arribute15, 
for every parent object in `List<Parent>`. How should I do this using Java 8 concepts(specially streams).
(please don't give me a solution of iterating each parent through a for loop and get the `childlist` and sort it.)

Comment: When you have so many attributes, probably it's time to switch to dynamic attributes instead (storing name-value pairs in `HashMap` or probably `EnumMap`)... Also `Comparator<Parent> byFirst = Comparator.comparing(Parent::getAttrib1);` looks better for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the `Parent`s with `forEach` and then sort the `Child` list:

```
resultSet.stream()
        .forEach(p -> p.getChildList().sort(Comparator.comparing(Child::getAttrib15)));
```